Issue with eventEmitter Communication Between Service and Gateway in Nestjs
currently I'm working on my project and encountered a specific issue. I can't figure out why eventEmitter isn't working between the service and the gateway. Here's a code example:
// chat.service.ts
async test(payload: object) {
  this.eventEmitter.emit('chat.test', payload);
    return {
      test: true
  }
}

// chat.gateway.ts
@OnEvent('chat.test')
async handleTest(payload: object) {
  socket.emit('test', payload)
}

Sockets are working, eventEmitter works fine between services, but it's not working between the service and the gateway.
As for the need: I have a situation where a chat is created by another service through an eventEmitter trigger, and I need the newly created chat to be immediately loaded for the user.
I would appreciate any help or advice. Perhaps there's another solution to achieve this? Always open to discussion.
I read somewhere that eventEmitter only works in providers, maybe that's why it's not working.

I've found a viable solution to address my issue:
In the chat.service.ts file, it's essential to initialize eventEmitter outside the constructor within the class with public access. Following this, to ensure the proper functioning of event handlers, can employ the following approach:
// chat.service.ts
import { EventEmitter2 } from 'eventemitter2';

export class TestService {
  eventEmitter: EventEmitter2 = new EventEmitter2();

  async test(payload: object) {
    this.eventEmitter.emit('chat.test', payload);
    return {
      test: true
    };
  }
}

In the chat.gateway.ts file, should connect the event handling function within the constructor as illustrated below:
// chat.gateway.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { TestService } from './chat.service';

@Injectable()
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  constructor(private readonly chatService: TestService) {
    this.chatService.eventEmitter.on('chat.test', response => {
      this.handleTest(response);
    });
  }

  async handleTest(payload: object) {
    socket.emit('test', payload);
  }
}

